# How to get preferred language from settings in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am looking for a way to get what language is on top of preferred list in `Settings` in user's device. I just want to get the language and nothing else. I have tried using following but all are returning `en`.

```
Locale.current
Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
Locale.current.languageCode
Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0]
```

Here is the screenshot of settings page

[image]

However, if I change region, then it reflects the region correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked Schemes > Run > Options > App Language? If you run your app, it uses what you have set there. If you force close and reboot the app, without debugger attached, it will use what is set in the iOS settings.

Comment: `Locale.preferredLanguages` returns an array of language codes (with regional variants - for example, English might be `en-US` or `en-GB` or `en-AU` and so on) that the user has set as "Preferred Languages". Assuming your device in your screen-shot has Region set to España, your should get `["es-ES", "en-ES"]`

Comment: In my case, it is always returning a single language and that is always `en` with regional code .e.g if region is Thailand, it will return `en-Th`. 
I am testing this with debugger attached.

Comment: In your question, you show that you tried `Locale.preferredLanguages[0]` ... have you tried `print(Locale.preferredLanguages)` ?

Comment: @DonMag, yes I tried and it was showing only single language that was `en`

Comment: Try it again. Are you using Simulators or physical Devices?

Comment: I have tried both.